# Cannot bind array data to Lightbox attribute

Tags: angular, angularjs, typescript

**gallery1.url** binds to the href attribute perfectly but **gallery1.ref_id** does not bind data to the data-lightbox attribute, but if I use that same **gallery1.ref_id** inside of an HTML paragraph tag it shows data perfectly. what am I doing wrong?

```
<a
 href="{{ gallery1.url }}"
 data-lightbox="{{ gallery1.ref_id }}"
 data-title="Caption8"
>
  <img
     src="{{ gallery1.url }}"
     alt="image"
     style="width: 100%"
  />
</a>
```

Comment: Use [attr.data-lightbox]=“ gallery1.ref_id”

Comment: is this angular or angularjs?

Comment: @Kinglish this is angularJS

Answer (score 0):

As @MikeOne mentioned in the comment this method works perfectly.

```
[attr.data-lightbox]= "gallery1.ref_id"
```

Full example:

```
<a
 href="{{ gallery1.url }}"
 [attr.data-lightbox]= "gallery1.ref_id"
 data-title="Caption8"
>
  <img
     src="{{ gallery1.url }}"
     alt="image"
     style="width: 100%"
  />
</a>
```